# how to erase or hide text box text while clicking textbox? c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I have to hide text box text while clicking text box. Help me to find a proper solution.
Thank You.

On page load the text box displayed like given below:
[image]

While click on the text box, I have to hide that text.

[image]

ASPX:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="150 px">Enter Team Name</asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: I know that, because you weren't here if any of them worked. Can you update the question with some of the methods you've tried? It will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `placeholder` attribute to achieve this. Like follwing

`<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="150" placeholder="Enter Team Name"></asp:TextBox>`

**NOTE:** This is HTML 5 specific attribute and will only work in HTML5 browser(Most used browsers now-a-days are html5 browsers, with few exception such as IE7,8,9).

**Advantage** - No JS,CSS, Event required to achieve this, it will direct start supporting requirement here.

More info here - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_placeholder.

But anyways, you can use `mordenizer.js` to make it work in all browsers - http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-html5-placeholder-text

Answer (score 0):

the length is  a  property in textbox object  that  can controle  the  value

try  this i hope  to help

```
  protected void TextBox1_Click(object sender, Eventargs e)
{
 TextBox1.Text.Length = 0;
}
```